# Complex Query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on an sql query where i am receiving data in three different rows, i really need the data in one single row

```
SELECT
substring(D.F1056, patindex('%[^0]%',D.F1056), 10) as Shop_Number,
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D.F254, 103), '/', '') AS Todays_Date,
SDP_TAB.F03  as Rayon,
[SDP_TAB].F04 as Famille,
CASE 
WHEN D.F1034=3 THEN SUM(D.F64) 
                            ELSE 0 
END as Qty_Sold ,
CASE 
WHEN D.F1034=3 THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, SUM(D.F65)*100) * 10
                            ELSE 0 
END as chiffre_daffaire_Caisse,
0 as montant_remisse_caisse,
CASE
WHEN D.F1034=3011 THEN SUM(D.F64) 
WHEN D.F1034=3012 THEN SUM(D.F64) 
                            ELSE 0 
END as Qty_retour,
CASE
WHEN D.F1034=3011 THEN SUM(D.F65) 
WHEN D.F1034=3012 THEN SUM(D.F65) 
                            ELSE 0 
END as Montant_Retour,
0 as Quantity,
CASE
WHEN D.F1034=3102 THEN SUM(D.F64) 
                            ELSE 0 
END as ClientCount,
F1034
FROM 
            [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] D
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[POS_TAB] ON (D.F01=POS_TAB.F01)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].SDP_TAB ON (POS_TAB.F04=SDP_TAB.F04)

where 
            D.F1034 IN (3,3012,3011,3102)
            AND
            D.F254 = convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)     
group by D.F1056,D.F254,SDP_TAB.F03,SDP_TAB.F04,D.F1034
```

My data is being populated as below [image: Populated Data]

I am having three rows since i am having several condition for field F1034

Is there a way to have the expected result as below [image]

Comment: I think you absolutely need to tell us the logic for how those three records become one record.  It is not clear just by looking at your example.

Comment: Please consider editing your tags. I don't see any c#, nor mysql or vb.net in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I think he wants to "flatten" his results. Meaning, if there's a 0, it should be ignored. Also, I guess there's some kind of `SUM` to do with these lines...

Comment: Can you edit your post to clarify the rules on why the values are selected? It seems from your final image that you want duplicate rows to be removed and for rows where all values except one are 0, that you only want to see the non-zero value, but what about the `7` in `F64`? Why was that shown instead of the `1` and `2`?

Comment: @Atlasmaybe: Perhaps you should look at the two images to see why Tim commented as he did.

Comment: @alaa_sayegh: You should look at the images to see why this approach will not work.

Comment: Actually,i have to send the details as in one row to an external party..but my table is populated with several Totalizer Functions which is the field F1034 where it can take the value of 3011,3012 and 3. @DaveyDaveDave The need to take the value of F64 since i need this value for the condition F1034 = 3 .. Qty_Retour and Montant_Retour is being populated on Condition F1034 = 3011... But at the end i really need the data all together...

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I have rerun the query, please see the updated image how the data is being populated.If i remove the column F1034, Can i merge the data ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very unclear about the rules how *how* you want to get "the data all together". Are the values in the ultimate output row the sum of all the rows (you mention "Totalizer Functions"), or is it one selected based on the content in other columns (you mentioned that you "need to take the value of F64 since i need this value for the condition F1034 = 3"). I'd suggest you edit your quesiton to add, for each column individually, how you determine the value that you want to see in the final output.

Comment: i am sorry , i am having a hard time in expressing what i really want. Actually Qty_retour, Qty_Sold have different totalizer ID(F1034) for the field F64.. I guess the right output is here but i only need the individual result of each column

Comment: In column F1034, how did you come up with just '3' as the final value when aggregated into just one row?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar Actually, i have display the field F1034 for illustration, at the end i will omit this field. I have changed the output result.Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. (Using max with calculated columns)

```
With  resultData as (

—Put your original query here

 )
Select Shop_Number, Todays_Date,rayon,famille
,max(Qty_Sold) Qty_Sold, max(chiffre_daffaire_Caisse) chiffre_daffaire_Caisse
,max(montant_remisse_caisse) montant_remisse_caisse,max(Qty_retour) Qty_retour,max(Montant_Retour) Montant_Retour
,max(Quantity)Quantity,max(ClientCount) ClientCount,max(F1034) F1034
From resultData 
group by Shop_Number, Todays_Date,rayon,famille
```